# How to dynamically render Route components in React-router-dom and React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

So, I want to create routes this way:

```
<Routes>
  {
    SidebarItems.map(el => 
      <Route key={el.text} path={el.link} element={<el.text/>}/>
    )
  }
</Routes>
```

SidebarItems

```
export const SidebarItems: Array<SidebarItem> = [
    {
        text: "Educatie",
        icon: SchoolIcon,
        link: '/educatie'
    },
    {
        text: "Experienta",
        icon: DoneIcon,
        link: '/experienta'
    },
    {
        text: "Judete",
        icon: MapIcon,
        link: '/judete'
    },
    {
        text: "Localitati",
        icon: MapsHomeWorkIcon,
        link: '/localitati'
    },
    {
        text: "Tipuri de contract",
        icon: ArticleIcon,
        link: '/tipuricontract'
    }
];
```

The components have the name from the text property.
I observed that if I explicitly call a component, like:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Educatie/>}/>
```

it will work. But only using a text doesn't work - I need to reference the component itself.

How can I do that in my specific case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```js
const Component1 = React.lazy(() =>
  import ('./Component1'));
const Component2 = React.lazy(() =>
  import ('./Component2'));

const componentHandler = (text) => {
  switch text {
    case 'component 1':
      return <Component1 / > ;
    case 'component 2':
      return <Component2 / >
        default:
        null
  }
}

//////////
{
  SidebarItems.map(el =>
    <Route key = {el.text}
    path = {el.link}
    element={componentHandler(el.text)}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: this did it. Is there any way to do it more dynamic though? (without having to explicitly import each of them first)

Comment: I guess that can be implemented only for state less and mostly containing static html components. you can get html from server and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render html content inside component